# Filter array by finding multiple conditions in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, javascript-objects

I have an array with a nested array of objects, I want to filter the data where the object of the nested arrays meets multiple conditions.

Here's the sample data.

```
const providerList = [
  {
    id: "bac4ef8d",
    provider_name: 'Paa Ra'
    provider_gender: "Male",
    provider_item: [
      {
        itemID: "5911319b"
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      },
      {
        itemID: "937a56d7"
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: "9df373d5",
    provider_name: "Che Ta",
    provider_gender: "Female",
    provider_item: [
      {
        itemID: "5911319b"
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

These are the filters, note that the `itemID` can have any number of elements.

```
const itemFilter = {
  itemID: ["5911319b", "937a56d7"],
  is_approved: [true],
  is_active: [true],
};
```

Here's my code, however the output does not return as desired.

```
const filterProviders = providerList.filter(provider =>
  provider.provider_item.every(item =>
    Object.entries(itemFilter).every(([k, v]) => v.includes(item[k]))),
);
```

I require to filter the `providerList` and returning providers where the
`provier_item` **matches all values in** `itemFilter`. The expected output for the above `itemFilter` would be:

```
filterProviders = [
  {
    id: "bac4ef8d",
    provider_name: 'Paa Ra'
    provider_gender: "Male",
    provider_item: [
      {
        itemID: "5911319b"
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      },
      {
        itemID: "937a56d7"
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: do you want to have all `itemID` of nested `provider_item` or just some?

Comment: @jsejcksn I've updated to show the output.

Comment: @NinaScholz the return would require all, not some

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after:

```js
const providerList = [{
    id: "bac4ef8d",
    provider_name: 'Paa Ra',
    provider_gender: "Male",
    provider_item: [{
        itemID: "5911319b",
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      },
      {
        itemID: "937a56d7",
        is_approved: true,
        is_active: true,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "9df373d5",
    provider_name: "Che Ta",
    provider_gender: "Female",
    provider_item: [{
      itemID: "5911319b",
      is_approved: true,
      is_active: true,
    }],
  }
]

const itemFilter = {
  itemID: ["937a56d7", "5911319b"],
  is_approved: [true],
  is_active: [true],
}

const filterProviders = providerList.reduce((acc, provider) => {
  provider.provider_item = provider.provider_item.filter(item => (
    itemFilter.itemID.every(ai => provider.provider_item.map(i => i.itemID).includes(ai)) &&
    itemFilter.is_approved.includes(item.is_approved) &&
    itemFilter.is_active.includes(item.is_active)
  ))

  let providerCount = provider.provider_item.length

  if (providerCount > 0 && providerCount === itemFilter.itemID.length) {
    acc.push(provider)
  }

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(filterProviders)
```

Comment: Thanks, however, if I add another ```itemID``` to the itemFilter like ```itemID: ["937a56d7", "5911319b"```, the I get both results, however, I should get only provide with name 'Paa Ra'. The other user with name 'Che Ta' does not have both ```itemID``` so I should not return  it

Comment: This important piece of information was missing at time of my posting.  I have now updated my answer.

Comment: something's not adding up, for Provider 'Paa Ra', let's say we add a third ```provider_item``` where ```is_active``` and ```is_approved``` equates to true, and in the ```itemFilter``` the ```itemID``` is not chosen, then I still get the result for 'Paa Ra' which should not be the case, it should have returned null, because the ```itemFilter.itemID``` should match what's shown in the ```provider``` array

Comment: In that case, you can additionaly check to see if filtered providerList has the same number of providers as the filter.  I have updated my answer again.